# ionic - Tesseract & Parsing MRZ

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to get the value from Tesseract's OCR into an MRZ parser, to no avail. If I pass a string, manually, it works as expected and MRZ parsed details are shown.

Imports:

```
import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'
import * as mrzParser from 'newtondev-mrz-parser';
```

Function:

```
Tesseract.create({
    langPath: "https://github.com/Exteris/tesseract-mrz/blob/master/lang/OCRB.traineddata.gz?raw=true"
  }).recognize(document.getElementById('image'), "ocrb")
    .progress((progress) => {
        console.log('progress', JSON.stringify(progress));
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .then(tesseractResult => {

       //the alert works and shows the actual text from an image
       alert(tesseractResult.text); 

       //manually passing the string works
       var xdata  = 'P<CANMARTIN<<SARAH<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ZE000509<9CAN8501019F2301147<<<<<<<<<<<<<<08';

       //this does *not* work
       //var xdata  = tesseractResult.text;

       this.imageText = mrzParser.parse(xdata);
       alert(JSON.stringify(this.imageText));

    })

    .finally(resultOrError => console.log(resultOrError));
```

Nothing in the error logs unfortunately.